# How can I send image to program with import instead of saving it?

Tags: linux, bash

Instead of

```
import -window root image.png
```

I want to send the image to standard output or directly to a python program.

Comment: Your code is not Python. Please explain what you want to happen.

Comment: I want to check some pixels in application window even if its minimized.
import -w id works fine but i dont want to safe it and then open the same screenshot with another program to check it.
Is there a way to directly pass the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

I've removed the Python tag, as this is a general question. `man import` reveals advice to "Specify 'file' as '-' for  standard  input  or output." So use an output file name of `-` and then (if you want) pipe that into the program of your choice.